# how to apply background image in xamarin IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xcode5, xamarin

I am creating  XAMARIN IOS Application on MAC Platform. I have create a login screen and apply a background image using xcode interface builder and synchronize by my xamarin code.but the issue is **when i am running my xamarin app then background image is not appearing**. Is there any setting needed. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was the problem in name of image....I have change the name of image default.png to xyz.png.then it works.